# .click add a piece of json into a panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Ive been desperately trying to get this to work.

Iknow there are probably better ways to do this other than the way I am trying but its for an assignment and has to be done this way.

I am creating a simple shopping cart/ the cart does not have to add a total just get the items inside of the panel (if anyone knew how to add the price also that would be brilliant but not 100% necessary)

So I have displayed items of json using json and ajax, on page ready the items are on show as so (there are about 12 items):

[image: items in page]

so I have the panel hidden, when the user clicks on a button (the blue button) I want the json information and the json price to appear inside the panel.

here is a snip of one of the items from my json file (which is called **result.json**:

```
{
    "appleitems":[
        {
            "Product_id":"Iphone5",
            "Information":"Iphone 5 64GB",
            "Imgpath":"image/iphone5.jpg",
            "Price":"200.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

This ishow my items are displayed:

```
$.getJSON('iproducts.json',function(products){
    var output = "";
    $.each(products.appleitems, function(i, product) { 

        output += 
            "<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3\"><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-footer'><h4 class='text-center'>"  
            + products.appleitems[i].Product_id 
            + "</h4></div>" + "<img src ='" + products.appleitems[i].Imgpath + "'  style='width:100%;height:250px; display: block;' id='appleinfo_" 
            + products.appleitems[i].Product_id + "' /><h5 class='text-center'>"    + products.appleitems[i].Information
            + "</h5><div class='panel-footer'>`<button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' id='btnadd'>&pound;" + products.appleitems[i].Price+"</button>`</div></div></div>";
    });

    $("#container").html(output);
});
```

and you will notice the button that I want clicked to display the json is **btnadd**:

```
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' id='btnadd'>&pound;" + products.appleitems[i].Price+"</button>
```

so when the user clicks btn add I want the json "information" and "price" to display inside of the pannel **cart**:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body" id="cart"></div>
```

I have started the script for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide alert when page loads
    $("#cart").hide();
    //get the item into the panel
    $("#btnadd").click(function(event){
        $.getJSON('result.json', function(add) {
           ...
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You are having same Id value for all the buttons(inside the loop). Duplicate Id's are not valid. So may be you can remove that and add a css class to the button for the jQuery selection. Also i would recommend keeping the price and information in HTML5 data attributes on the button for easier read.

```
var output ="";
$.each(products.appleitems, function(i, product) { 

   output += "<div><div>"

   output +="<button class='btn btn-primary btn-block addBtn' data-info='"+ 
          product.Price +"' data-price='"+
          product.Information +"'>&pound;" + product.Price+"</button>";

   output +="</div></div>";
});
```

And listen to the `click` event on this specific css class

```
$(function(){

  $(document).on("click",".addBtn",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this=$(this);
    var c=_this.data("info") + " " +_this.data("price");
    $("#cart").html(c);
  });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/fawoya/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: Hi Shyju, thank you very much for your help but this did not work for me, is there any way of sending you my code to look at?

Comment: I just posted an update to the answer which includes a link to a working jsbin. That should help you going.

Comment: shyju you are very kind! I appreciare that! I will try this out

Comment: shyju.. this works but unfortunately my panels containing the items mess up :(

Comment: something wrong with your CSS or HTML. add a simple div in your $.each loop with just the price, if it works, add the button, then image. that way you know where it is adding the wrong markup